# How to add speaker labels in AWS Transcribe streaming websockets

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-transcribe, speaker-diarization

I'm using the AWS Transcribe example from https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-transcribe-websocket-static with a simple modification on the websocket query-string to add speaker labels.

The current websocket URL path and querystring are `/stream-transcription-websocket` and `?language-code=it-IT&media-encoding=pcm&sample-rate=16000&show-speaker-label=true&max-speaker-label=10` but the returned event messages are exactly the same as those without speaker label inserted.

What is the correct query-string for the current use-case?